# DLE открытие внутренних ссылок в новой вкладке

Tags: php, javascript, html, seo, dle

Как сделать что бы все внутренние ссылки открывались в новой вкладке?(Как минимум с главной и категорий на новости и с новостей на категории) Вероятно в скрипте отвечающем за вывод ссылок можно добавить target="_blank". Что это за скрипт, как добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно как-то так, подработаете под себя

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
           window.open(this.href, '_blank');
       });
   }
});
});
```

Comment: Использовал этот скрипт- благодарю.